# Pattern Rule is not working as expected

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have part of a GNU-make makefile (gcc v4.1.2) that is not working as I would expected. I have a four libraries in sub diretiories that I want to recursively build if `make` is ran in the base /build directory

```
/prj
|--/build
|  |--makefile
|  |--/Tables.lib
|  |  |--makefile
|  |--/General.lib
|  |  |--makefile (etc..)
|--/lib
|--/src
```

Brief code for /prj/build/makefile:

```
LIB_DIR = /prj/lib

LIBRARY := libcomposition_adjustment.a libtables.a libgeneral.a libbiblio.a
DIRS := Tables.lib Composition_adjustment.lib General.lib Biblio.lib

all: $(LIBRARY)
#all: $(LIB_DIR)/libcomposition_adjustment.a # this line works

%.a : $(LIB_DIR)/%.a

$(LIB_DIR)/libtables.a:
    cd Tables.lib; $(MAKE)

$(LIB_DIR)/libcomposition_adjustment.a:
    cd Composition_adjustment.lib; $(MAKE)

$(LIB_DIR)/libgeneral.a:
    cd General.lib; $(MAKE)

$(LIB_DIR)/libbiblio.a: libgeneral.a
    cd Biblio.lib; $(MAKE)
```

It says that "No rule to make target 'libcomposition_adjustment.a', needed by 'all'. stop". But I thought the line `%.a : $(LIB_DIR)/%.a` would handle that. I am making this pattern rule incorrectly?

If i try the second `all:` line that is commented out, it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
%.a : $(LIB_DIR)/%.a
```

This is a pattern rule with no commands, which Make does not interpret as an independent rule at all. There's more than one way to fix this; the simplest is probably to give it a do-nothing command:

```
%.a : $(LIB_DIR)/%.a
    @:
```

but a better way is to do without the questionable rule altogether:

```
LIB_DIR = /prj/lib

LIBRARY := libcomposition_adjustment.a libtables.a libgeneral.a libbiblio.a
LIBRARY := $(addprefix $(LIB_DIR)/,$(LIBRARY))

all: $(LIBRARY)

$(LIB_DIR)/libtables.a:
    cd Tables.lib; $(MAKE)

$(LIB_DIR)/libcomposition_adjustment.a:
    cd Composition_adjustment.lib; $(MAKE)

$(LIB_DIR)/libgeneral.a:
    cd General.lib; $(MAKE)

$(LIB_DIR)/libbiblio.a: $(LIB_DIR)/libgeneral.a
    cd Biblio.lib; $(MAKE)
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense that it has to do "something" even if it doesn't do anything.